# Telegram API: SESSION_REVOKED

Tags: telegram

Кто-нибудь может пояснить, что это за ошибка и как с ней бороться?

Comment: может поможет
https://github.com/vysheng/tg/issues/73

Comment: @AliaksandrPitkevich, сейчас попробую...

Comment: @AliaksandrPitkevich, Большое спасибо! Все заработало!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы должны удалить ваши файлы авторизации (они по умолчанию находятся в папке .telegram). Если вы используете `binlog`, это только файл binlog, если нет - `'auth', 'state' и 'secret'`. И затем снова авторизуйтесь.

Comment: У мну немного не те файлы, но очень сильно помог этот совет!!!!